# How to retrieve/fetch items from Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: api, rest, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am New to Programming, Started with Flutter, Following Some Tutorials Making Progress Slowly.

i am adding data on **Firebase Real Time Database** with the help of this URL:

- final url = 'https://MyFirebaseLink.firebaseio.com/orders/**$userId**.json?auth=$authToken';

All Items are saving under orders>**Unique-uid-Stirng**>Key>Fields

i am able to retrieve Single item with this URL:

- final url = 'https://MyFirebaseLink.firebaseio.com/orders/(e.g uid Sting)**XYZABC123AnXYZABC**.json?auth=$authToken';

How i can retrieve all records saved under different uids tried these URLs:

Below first two url retrieving only logged in users Fields

- final url = 'https://MyFirebaseLink.firebaseio.com/orders.json?auth=$authToken';
- final url = 'https://MyFirebaseLink.firebaseio.com/orders/.json?auth=$authToken';

Looking for solution like below URLs:

- final url = 'https://MyFirebaseLink.firebaseio.com/orders/*.json?auth=$authToken';
- final url = 'https://MyFirebaseLink.firebaseio.com/orders/*/.json?auth=$authToken';

Or is there any alternate way where i can achieve the same (Edited: Only looking for Real Database Solutions).

Would appreciate your answers Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
final db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("orders");
db.orderByKey().once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
  var uids = snapshot.value.keys;
  var data = snapshot.value;
    for (var key in uids) {
      var newList = data[key];
      print(newList);
    }
```

Above code solved the Problem that I have asked as an alternate way.

Below is the full code to fetch order as an admin user to change order status:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetAdminOrders() async {
List<OrderItem> orderList = [];
    final db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("orders");
db.orderByKey().once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
  var uids = snapshot.value.keys;
  var data = snapshot.value;
    for (var key in uids) {
      var newList = data[key];
      print(newList);



  newList.forEach((orderId, orderData) {
    orderList.add(
      OrderItem(
        id: orderId,
        amount: orderData['amount'],
        status: orderData['status'],
        dateTime: DateTime.parse(orderData['dateTime']),
        products: (orderData['products'] as List<dynamic>)
            .map((item) => CartItem(
          id: item['id'],
          price: item['price'],
          quantity: item['quantity'],
          title: item['title'],
        ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );

  });
    }
  _orders = orderList.reversed.toList();
  notifyListeners();
});}
```

It is Working Well and displaying all orders with their status, except few errors like below.

```
E/flutter (10256): A Orders was used after being disposed.
E/flutter (10256): Once you have called dispose() on a Orders, it can no longer be used.
```